# Angularjs best practices for referencing child elements in a directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say you have a directive template like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <!--This is the element I want to reference-->
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know I could reference the element like so:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   element.children().children().children....
}
```

But this approach doesn't seems very eloquent.

Should I make the elements I want to reference child directive and pass in the parent controller?

Or is there another approach that I'm missing that would work better here?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do with this directive (and the child elements)?

Comment: @Rob can You give me a feedback for my answer ?

Comment: @Rob If you wanted to assign a click handler, you could just give it an `ng-click` attribute in the directive's template, and specify a function in the directive's scope. If this isn't possible, then I think the specifics would be needed to advise you.

Answer (score 1):

#### I would create a more "generic" directive so it could be reused anywhere:

here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/q5H8ydH73UB4TtOtGT1r?p=preview

**generic directive:**

```
app.directive('ref',function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope,el,attrs){
      scope[attrs.ref] = el;

      // we should clean up to avoid memory leaks        
      el.on('$destroy',function(){
        scope[attrs.ref] = null;  
      });
    }
  }
})
```

**template:**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <!--This is the element I want to reference-->
            <div ref="hello">
              hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**your directive:**

```
link: function(scope){
  // now you have it on your scope!
  scope.hello.append('<span> world !</span>')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't put a reference like class="myclass"
take a look to

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

you can use it also without include jquery library

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element